# Convert a query results from lines to columns so i can see somes values from a column in columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Just need to have just 1 line  from this query (that returns several lines due to the columns "Questão" to right.
I'll need to have each value of that columns in a column so i can have just one line for each ref

[image]

```
Declare @design         varchar(80) =   ''          -- 
Declare @ref            varchar(18) =   ''          -- 001131639,0010167
Declare @fornecedor     varchar(55) =   ''          -- 
Declare @DocOri         varchar(10) =   ''          -- 
Declare @datarec        varchar(10) = '20200114'    -- 
Declare @Lote           varchar(30) = '001131624'   -- 

Select 

    'Ref'                       =   convert(varchar(80),bi.ref) 
    ,'Artigo'                   =   convert(varchar(80),bi.design)
    ,'Quant.'                   =   bi.qtt
    ,'Unid.'                    =   bi.unidade
    ,'Marca'                    =   bi.marca
    ,'Lote'                     =   isnull(se.lote,'-')
    ,'Data Validade'            =   isnull(convert(CHAR(10),se.validade,121),'-')
    ,'Fornecedor'               =   bo.nome
    ,'Doc'                      =   convert(varchar(80),bo.nmdos)
    ,'Doc_n'                    =   convert(varchar(80),bo.obrano)
    ,'Doc_data'                 =   convert(Char(10),bo.dataobra,121)
    ,'Doc Origem'               =   isnull(bo.obranome,'-')
    ,'Questão'                  =   convert(varchar(80),qst.descricao)
    ,'Q_A rotulagem da Caixa  Master está conforme?' = Case when 
    ,'Resultado Geral'          =   convert(varchar(80),cab.resultado)
    ,'É difinitivo'             =   convert(varchar(80),cab.definitivo)
    ,'Avaliaçao Artigo'         =   convert(varchar(80),lin.avaliacao)
    ,'Resultado Geral Artigo'   =   convert(varchar(80),lin.resultado)

from bi
    inner join bo on bi.bostamp=bo.bostamp and bo.ndos=17
    inner join u_avalcab cab on bistamp=cab.oristamp
    inner join u_avallin lin on cab.u_avalcabStamp=lin.u_avalcabstamp
    inner join u_crit qst on lin.u_critstamp = qst.u_critstamp
    left join se On bi.ref=se.ref and bi.lote=se.lote

Where 
    (CASE WHEN @ref= '' THEN 1 else case when bi.ref = @ref then 1 else 0 end end) = 1 
    and (CASE WHEN @design ='' THEN 1 else case when bi.design like '%' +  @design + '%' then 1 else 0 end end) = 1
    and (CASE WHEN @fornecedor='' THEN 1 else case when bo.nome Like '%' +  @fornecedor + '%' then 1 else 0 end end) = 1
    and (CASE WHEN @datarec='' THEN 1 else case when bo.dataobra = @datarec then 1 else 0 end end) = 1 
    and (CASE WHEN @Docori='' THEN 1 else case when bo.nmdos = @Docori then 1 else 0 end end) = 1 
    and (CASE WHEN @Lote='' THEN 1 else case when se.lote = @Lote then 1 else 0 end end) =1

order by Doc,Doc_data
```

---

What i need is to convert the multiline result to one line with more columns

As you see in the image, teher is several lines with same information. I want to maintain in just one line.
The columens with diferente information, I want to convert to different columns sou I can have it all in just one line to be used in a report

for example 
Ref / Artigo / .../ Q1_A rotulagem da Caixa  Master está conforme? / Valor Q1 / Q2_A rotulagem do Embalado está conforme? | Q2_......

Comment: you could use PIVOT operator, but could you please add an example of final result you wish to receive (including new column names)?

Answer (score 0):

For this example i am using this example query: `SELECT * FROM example`

First you need to define a variable which will hold the results. Because all results will be shown in one column the datatype of this column should be `varchar(x)` where x is large enough to hold the data you want to show. Of course the number of columns should match the number of columns of your query. In this example i will be using `SELECT a,b,c,d FROM example`, so my variable will look like:

```
DECLARE @a TABLE(a varchar(20),b varchar(20),c varchar(20),d varchar(20));
```

Next i will create some sample data:

```
WITH example(a, b, c, d) as (
     SELECT 'een', 1, 'one',1.1
     union all
     SELECT 'twee', 2, 'two', 2.2
     union all
     SELECT 'drie', 3, 'three', 3.3
)  
select * into #tempTable from example
```

If we select this:

```
select 
    x.name,   
    --x.column_ordinal,
    CASE x.column_ordinal
        WHEN 1 THEN a.a 
        WHEN 2 THEN CAST(a.b as varchar(80))
        WHEN 3 THEN a.c 
        WHEN 4 THEN CAST(a.d as varchar(80)) 
        END as value

from #tempTable as a
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT name, column_ordinal 
    FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set
        ('SELECT * FROM #tempTable', NULL, 0) 
    ) x
;
```

The output looks like:

```
name       value
---------- ------------
a          een
b          1
c          one
d          1.1
a          twee
b          2
c          two
d          2.2
a          drie
b          3
c          three
d          3.3
```

Because my query returns 3 records with 4 fields, this query returns 12 records (4 sets of 3 records).

see also [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=319e519fc3db074d19e68a2f2e2dac21)